# auto change local url into online url in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

When we use to make our local project online in wordpress then we have to change the url of images according to live project. Is there any way to change url from local project to live project automatically not manually.

Comment: There is a plugin for that [Go Live Update URLs](https://wordpress.org/plugins/go-live-update-urls/) . You can use that. I never used that plugin but the review and active installs shows that it is nice plugin. :)

Comment: Thanks! it seems to be perfect solution for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting my comment in to an answer so it can help others as well

> There is plugin in WordPress which can help you to update URLs of the localhost to live. Plugin name is [Go Live Update URLs](https://wordpress.org/plugins/go-live-update-urls/). With the help of that plugin you can change the URL easily.